# Rendered template output in toplinks

Tags: layout, template

I think this might be impossible but I thought I would ask from some of the Magento developers here.

I want to use the `'aftertext'` attribute when using the `addLink()` method of the top links block in `layout xml`.

But, I want to use the output of a rendered block/template for the value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I *think* you can do this via a helper method, which simply returns the html of the generated block as its result.

Something like this:

```
class ProxiBlue_ModuleIcons_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

    public function getBlockHtml(){

        $block = mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock(
                'MODULE/BLOCK', 'NAME.IN.LAYOUT');
        $html = $block->toHtml();
        return $html;

    }

}
```

Then in the addLink xml directive, call the helper method. 
As an example:

```
<reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log In</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
            <title>Log In</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
            <liParams/>
            <aParams>class="top-link-login"</aParams>
            <afterText helper="moduleicons/getBlockHtml"></afterText>
        </action>
    </reference>
```